# PostgreSQL: Find and delete duplicated jsonb data, excluding a key/value pair when comparing

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, jsonb

I have been searching all over to find a way to do this. 
I am trying to clean up a table with a lot of duplicated jsonb fields.
There are some examples out there, but as a little twist, I need to exclude one key/value pair in the jsonb field, to get the result I need.

Example jsonb

```
{
    "main": {
        "orders": {
            "order_id": "1"
            "customer_id": "1",
            "update_at": "11/23/2017 17:47:13"
        }
}
```

Compared to:

```
{
    "main": {
        "orders": {
            "order_id": "1"
            "customer_id": "1",
            "updated_at": "11/23/2017 17:49:53"
        }
}
```

If I can exclude the "updated_at" key when comparing, the query should find it  a duplicate and this, and possibly other, duplicated entries should be deleted, keeping only one, the first "original" one.

I have found this query, to try and find the duplicates. But it doesn't take my situation into account. Maybe someone can help structuring this to meet the requirements.

```
SELECT t1.jsonb_field
FROM customers t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT jsonb_field, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
            FROM customers
            GROUP BY jsonb_field
            HAVING COUNT(*)>1
            ) t2 ON t1.jsonb_field=t2.jsonb_field
WHERE 
t1.customer_id = 1
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the Updated at is always at the same path, then you can remove it:

```
SELECT t1.jsonb_field
FROM customers t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT jsonb_field, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
            FROM customers
            GROUP BY jsonb_field
            HAVING COUNT(*)>1
            ) t2 ON 
               t1.jsonb_field #-'{main,orders,updated_at}'
               =
               t2.jsonb_field #-'{main,orders,updated_at}'
WHERE 
t1.customer_id = 1
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html 
additional operators

---

EDIT

If you dont have #- you might just cast to text, and do a regex replace

```
regexp_replace(t1.jsonb_field::text, '"update_at": "[^"]*?"','')::jsonb
=
regexp_replace(t2.jsonb_field::text, '"update_at": "[^"]*?"','')::jsonb
```

I even think, you don't need to cast it back to jsonb. But to be save.

Mind the regex matche ANY "update_at" field (by key) in the json. It should not match data, because it would not match an escaped closing quote \", nor find the colon after it.

Note the regex actually should be `'"update_at": "[^"]*?",?'`
But on sql fiddle that fails. (maybe depends on the postgresbuild..., check with your version, because as far as regex go, this is correct)

If the comma is not removed, the cast to json fails.
you can try `'"update_at": "[^"]*?",'`
no ? : that will remove the comma, but fail if update_at was the last in the list.

worst case, nest the 2

```
 regexp_replace(
   regexp_replace(t1.jsonb_field::text, '"update_at": "[^"]*?",','')
 '"update_at": "[^"]*?"','')::jsonb
```

Comment: But as I understand it, this will delete the updated_at timestamps from the jsonb field right? I only want to remove it to compare jsonb fields without the timestamp.

Maybe I didn't explain it well. :-)


I need to compare multiple jasonb columns excluding the updated_at key/value pair (as that is different in each one, resulting in no duplicates).
If I can find those who differ only on updated_at, I need to delete all the duplicates except the newest. 

Sorry, I am finding it hard to explain, hope this helps. :-/

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood, and your suggestion is valid.
I am getting an error: 
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb #- unknown 
and I think this might be because I am running PostgreSQL 9.4, so the operator #- isn't available to me.. :-(

Comment: Thank you so much for the updated answer, and sorry for the late reply. 

Using the regex in your updated example, the query seems to be running infinitely. It just doesn't stop. 
Also replacing any updated_at in the json, is not so good, as only the one from that specific path (main->orders->updated_At) should be excluded from the comparison. 
Seems like a tedious task, yet it does not seem to be easily solved. 
I am wondering if updating Postgres and using #- would solve this...so maybe I will give that a try... :-/

Comment: hang on, it seems to work when I remove the cast back to ::jsonb
and as a small note, edit the field to updated_at instead of update_at...

Thanks again for your time and effort :-)

Answer (score 0):

for postgresql 9.4

Though sqlfidle only has 9.3 and 9.6

9.3 is missing the json_object_agg. But the postgres doc says it is in 9.4. So this *should* work

It will only work, if all records have objects under the important keys.
`main->orders`

If `main->orders` is a json array, or scalar, then this may give an error.
Same if `{"main": [1,2]}` => error.

Each `json_each` returns a table with a row for each key in the json

`json_object_agg` aggregates them back to a json array.

The case statement filters the one key on each level that needs to be handled.
In the deepest nest level, it filters out the updated_at row.

On sqlfidle set query separator to '//'
If you use psql client, replace the // with ;

```
create or replace function foo(x json) 
returns jsonb
language sql
as $$ 
  select json_object_agg(key,
  case key when 'main' then
    (select json_object_agg(t2.key,
    case t2.key when 'orders' then
      (select json_object_agg(t3.key, t3.value)
      from json_each(t2.value) as t3
       WHERE t3.key <> 'updated_at'
      )
    else  t2.value
    end)
    from json_each(t1.value) as t2
    )
  else t1.value
  end)::jsonb
  from json_each(x) as t1
$$ //

select foo(x)
from 
(select '{ "main":{"orders":{"order_id": "1", "customer_id": "1", "updated_at": "11/23/2017 17:49:53" }}}'::json as x) as t1
```

x (the argument) may need to be jsonb, if that is your datatype